# Parallel structure in sentence

Tags: grammar

> "Starting from nothing but a tree, and less than one working day, John built a chair and a table."

Is the usage of "and less than one working day" correct here? I believe that it should be "**in** less than one working day."

If so, what grammatical rule dictates this?

Comment: Yes, it should be 'in'. I'm not sure exactly why, there's probably a word for it.

Comment: By the way, could you include the research you have done, and why you came to your conclusion?

Comment: As it stands, 'less than one working day' modifies 'John', or arguably a starting material,  which is nonsense. But 'in less than one working day' is a temporal adverbial addressing how long the construction took John.

Comment: I posted it for the same reason--I wasn't sure exactly why and was curious if there was a rule for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another variant of the insidious [**Oxford comma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) or its jokey equivalent [**Eats, Shoots, and Leaves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves).

The sentence is actually fine without the "in", and could be paraphrased as follows:

**Starting with nothing but a tree and a day's labor,** John built a chair and a table.

Think [**euphony**](https://literarydevices.net/euphony/), which is sometimes clarity's friend.  Grammar is only part of the answer here.